# Android app try to open pdf file but is sent back right away

Tags: android, pdf, permissions, storage, android-10.0

My Android app allow users send message to each others with attachments, the problem is:

When user taps on a message attachment to open it, in this case is PDF file, app will ask system for another application to open the attachment and send user to that app along with the file, everything was working fine on Android 9 and older but **Android 10**, the pdf viewer app appears shortly in just 1 second then user is sent back to my app, issue occurs mostly on Samsung devices.

I tried android:requestLegacyExternalStorage but did not help.

Can anybody help on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: With the new permission settings of Android you need to give access to the PDF App to your file. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60967854/2110483

Comment: Hi @devz, thanks for reminding me, I knew it but somehow forgot to do it for that app @.@, thanks again